Collapsing Multiple Fields into a Key-Value Struct with Rust Polars 0.43
I want to collapse a number of columns in a DataFrame into a Key-Value struct prior to saving out to Parquet, ignoring any empty cells. For example:
|  id  |  a  |  b  |  c  |
| ---- | --- | --- | --- |
|    0 | Foo | Bar |     |
|    1 | Baz |     | Foo |

becomes
|  id  |  merged  |
| ---- | -------- |
|    0 | [{ key: "a", value: "Foo"}, { key: "b", value: "Bar" }] |
|    1 | [{ key: "a", value: "Baz"}, { key: "c", value: "Foo" }] |

Using Rust Polars v0.40 I could do this:
dataframe.with_columns([
    // Merge fields into single column
    as_struct(merge_fields)
        .map(move |s: Series| {
            // Downcast to a struct
            let chunked_array = s.struct_()?;

            // Get field names
            let names: Vec<&str> = chunked_array.fields_as_series().iter().map(|f| &f.name()).collect();

            // Loop over rows
            let out = chunked_array.into_iter().map(|row| {
                // Convert fields into pairs
                let merge_fields_as_strings = row.iter().enumerate().filter_map(|(idx, field)| {
                    let val = match field.get_str() {
                        Some(v) => v,
                        None => return None
                    };

                    if val.is_empty() || val.trim().is_empty() {
                        return None;
                    }

                    Some((names[idx], val))
                }).collect::<Vec<(&str, &str)>>();

                // Create data frame from pairs
                let d = df!(
                    "key" => merge_fields_as_strings.iter().map(|k| k.0).collect::<Vec<&str>>(),
                    "value" => merge_fields_as_strings.iter().map(|v| v.1).collect::<Vec<&str>>()
                ).unwrap();

                Some(d.select(["key", "value"]).unwrap().into_struct((&merged_name).into()).into_series())
            })
            .collect::<ChunkedArray<ListType>>();

            Ok(Some(out.into_series()))
        }, GetOutput::from_type(DataType::default())).alias(&self.field)])

However, I've just tried to update my dependencies to Rust Polars 0.43 and this no longer works because chunked_array.into_iter() (or now chunked_array.iter()) now returns an iterator over an empty type (from what I can see, for performance reasons).
What is the correct way to perform this operation now following the update?
